# Error console tell me to replace my "." to "," in an if statement (js)

Tags: javascript

I'm wondering if someone could help me. I'm trying to practice my js and css a bit and here's where the problem comes in. The error console says " ',' expected" where my "." before the innerHTML would be. I'm trying to build a theme switcher with only one button so it changes text when the button has the class for the light theme I want to change the text by using InnerHTML and it does exactly what my title says. Any idea why? Here's my code tho:

```
if(btnt)classList.contains('light', {
    switcher.InnerHTML = "Dark"
  });
```

Comment: Your code is syntactically wrong.

Comment: `btnt)classList` is wrong. Often the error is not the specific error, but very nearby

Comment: There are several syntax errors in your code, please go through JS basics

Comment: `if(btnt.classList.contains('light')) { switcher.InnerHTML = "Dark" }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a syntax error. The right way is:

```
if(btnt.classList.contains('light')) {
    switcher.InnerHTML = "Dark"
}
```